# How to update table column Id?

Tags: sql, auto-update

I want to update `Student` table where `student_id` is an auto-increment field. But I have deleted some students from the table, now I want to assign the ids again (i.e from 1 to last row value).

Comment: Why do the id values matter?

Comment: Why do you need to update those values? Pay attention if Student Table is referred somewhere else as a foreign key

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the auto increment for the students table.

```
ALTER TABLE Student AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good practise to update CD of a table. Anyway try yhis:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET ID = T.NEW_ID 
FROM (SELECT [ID_STUDENT] AS OLD_ID, 
             NEW_ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID_STUDENT] ORDER BY        [ID_STUDENT])) AS T
WHERE ID_STUDENT = T.OLD_ID
```